# Why GetPortNames method returns nothing?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am trying to send an SMS from computer to cell phone.
The first step: get all com ports to use it. 
I used this code, but no benefit:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] Ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
    foreach (string prt in Ports)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(prt);
    }
}
```

It returns nothing. What can I do?

Comment: Why would sending an SMS use a serial port?  Plenty of network-accessible SMS gateways.

Comment: Do you have cell phone connected to your PC (with a USB cable)?

Answer (score 8):

I just ran the following code on my PC and it returns "COM1":

```
        string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

        Console.WriteLine("The following serial ports were found:");
        foreach(string port in ports)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(port);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

So, it's either permissions or you don't have any Serial ports. Or perhaps your registry is corrupt?

Note:

> The port names are obtained from the system registry (for example,
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM). If the registry
>   contains stale or otherwise incorrect data then the GetPortNames
>   method will return incorrect data.

Ref: [SerialPort.GetPortNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: So how can i check if i have Serial ports or not and if my registry is corrupt or not ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue at first. Then realized that I didn't connect any device to my PC which identify themselves as a serial port (either via USB or any other physical port). It displayed accurately when I connected a device (a USB based PIC programmer in my case). Please check if your device is properly detected.